# join two files based on column when there is no one-to-one correspondence in bash script (awk, grep , sed)

Tags: bash, text-processing, sed, awk

file1.txt

```
112|9305|/inst.exe
112|9305|/lkj.exe
112|9305|/dje.jar
112|9305|/ind.pdf
112|9306|/ma.exe
112|9306|/ngg.pdf
112|9307|/jhhh.dat
112|9312|/ee.dat
112|9312|/qwq.dll
```

file2.txt

```
117|9305|www.gahan.com
117|9306|www.google.com
117|9312|www.mihan.com
117|9307|translate.com
```

I want output:

```
112|9305|www.gahan.com/inst.exe
112|9305|www.gahan.com/lkj.exe
112|9305|www.gahan.com/dje.jar
112|9305|www.gahan.com/ind.pdf
112|9306|www.google.com/ma.exe
112|9306|www.google.com/ngg.pdf
112|9307|translate.com/jhhh.dat
112|9312|www.mihan.com/ee.dat
112|9312|www.mihan.com/qwq.dll
```

I want to add the third column of `file2.txt` to the third column of `file1.txt` based on second column values. In fact, I want to join them based on the second column but there is **no one-to-one correspondence between them**. How can I do these with `awk` or `grep` or `sed` in shell script? Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

The task can be done by one **awk**:

```
awk -F'|' 'FNR==NR{host[$2]=$3;next}{$3=host[$2] $3}1' OFS='|' file2 file1
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a possible way to do it with `awk` and `sed` working in tandem:

```
awk -F'|' '{print "s/"$2"|""/"$2"|"$3"/"}' file2.txt | sed -f /dev/stdin file1.txt
```